# How to display elements with different sizes

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Whats up devs, so Im trying to display poster of movies in a grid, but some posters dont have the same size, and in some cases this what happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YOR8.png

I have this code I made with styled-components

```
    import styled from 'styled-components';
    
    const Container = styled.div `
       max-width: 1360px;
       padding-right: 15px;
       padding-left: 15px;
       margin-right: auto;
       margin-left: auto;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       &before,
       &:after {
           content: " ";
           display: table;
       }
       &:after {
           clear: both;
       }
    `;
    
    export const Row = styled.div`
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
       float: left;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       &:before,
       &:after {
           content: " ";
           display: table;
       }
       &:after {
           clear:both;
       }
     
    `;
    export const Column = styled.div`
       float: left;
       padding: 10px;
       min-height: 1px;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       width: 100%;
    
       img{
           width: 70%;
       }
    
       @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
           width: ${(3 / 12) * 100}%
       }
    `;

    export default Container;
```

Comment: What do you *wish* to happen? That all objects are displayed at the same size and don't fit like puzzle pieces?

Comment: yes, like this print https://i.imgur.com/Coxoovu.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could align your items with flexbox and adjust the size of your image to automatically fit your defined size. Here I make the image fit in height and width to prevent the image to be deformed. This lead to some white spaces (Exagerated here due to the size I defined of course, it will render as "ultimate avengers 2" in your screenshot) but it's still better than pixelized images I guess.

Here is [an example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-fhrbvf?file=index.js) and here is the code :

js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/600"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/3500/2400"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/600"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/600"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/600"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200"/></div>
      <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/600"/></div>

    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.container > *{
  margin: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

img{
  width:auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 200px
}
```

Note that I don't use grid/column/row here since flexbox already display it as you want it to be. It's way simplier.

Comment: Thank you, I modified your code a little bit and I can do it what I wanted. I have one doubt what this .container > *{ do?

Comment: You're welcome ! This code target every direct, and only direct, thanks to the '>') child of elements that have the class 'container'. without '>', it would target every sub node inside .container, until the last  level

Answer (score 0):

So with the help of [Quentin Grisel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9868549/quentin-grisel),  I modified the code he gave a little bit and I can get the solution.

Changes: I put fix values on the images, change the justify-content to flex-start.

the final result:
[image: search screen]

The final code:

```
    const Container = styled.div `
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  .container > *{
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #6b6b6b;
    text-align: center;
  }

    img{
        flex:1;
        width: 165px;
        height: 220px;
        margin: 10px;

      }
  }

`;


export default Container;
```

Comment: Be careful with `flex-start`, is does not manage the gap that could be left on the side of your container. Unfortunately, you can't mix `justify-content` with `flex-start` :(